# Android: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

I got an error while compiling my libgdx project with gradle.

```
Execution failed for task ':android:preDexAmazonDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /SDK-PATH/Android/build-tools/21.0.1/dx --dex --output /PATH/android/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/Amazon/debug/core-1.0-47e2423a0159bad5774996683a8ab834009ab7ed.jar /PATH/core/build/libs/core-1.0.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:279)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
  ...while parsing org/mars3142/OwnClass.class

    1 error; aborting
```

I didn't include **core** twice into my Android project. I double checked, if I include some external libs, but it seems, that my own project is the failure, which I can't understand, because I never changed something. I only added an android-wear project into my project. And if I go back into time (with git), it also is not compileable.

EDIT: If I hit **run** in **IntelliJ** for the same build variant (AmazonDebug) it works like expected. That's really strange.

Comment: Use build tools 20 instead of 21?

Comment: Didn't work. It's the same error.

Comment: It looks like that Amazon library file may be corrupted, or something else is going wrong at the file level.

Comment: It's a "product flavor" **Amazon** with nothing special. It's just a placeholder for later.

Comment: I tested it in IntelliJ and while pressing **run** there, everything works fine. It seems that **gradle** and **gradlew** from the commandline produces this error.